Contact Deletion + Auto Suppressions
I know that Auto Suppressions are considered Data Extensions so when you delete a Subscriber/Contact Key from the system it also deletes that Key from the Auto Suppression.
But I was wondering how this works on an Auto Suppression where you use the customers Email Address but when you delete contacts you use the Subscriber/Contact Key which for us is a hashed version of their email address.
I know for DE's it looks to see what records match that Contact Key so I assume if you use the actual Email Address with no Contact Key in the Auto Suppression it would not be deleted?


Contact Deletion works on Sendable Data Extensions.

Source
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5

"the Contact" in a data extension is marked using the Subscriber Relationship.  In other words, you use subscriber Relationship to explain your data extension to the system. The field you choose here is treated as "the Contact" for all purposes, including sendout (which makes them billable contacts) and also deletion.
This means that for the  delete operation, Contact Deletion references the field you set as "Subscriber Relationship" in each sendable DE.

==

An auto-suppression configuration is a data extension.
It is sendable.
Its send relationship is on the field "Email Address".

Source:
There are various ways to access an ASC via the normal data extension UI, (e.g. move it into another folder via API, access it with a contact builder deeplink and its object ID) and then you can simply visually check.

So: If you inject a Contact Key into Deletion, this will likely not delete anyone in an autosuppression, unless that Key is found in the field "Email Address" on said autosuppression.
That sounds pretty unlikely in your scenario as you specifically make the differentiation between email and Subscriber/Contact Key.
If you DO want to delete records from an autosuppression using Contact Deletion, you would need to actually inject Email Addresses into the Contact Deletion process; it would check all sendable data extensions in the system using their respective "Subscriber relationship" field, and it would find matches in your autosuppressions, thus deleting them.
